# FloatingPointError: invalid value encountered in greater_equal in Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin in QGIS

Tags: qgis, floating-point, scp

2019-04-05T00:29:33 WARNING Traceback (most recent call last):
File
"C:/Users/ASUS/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin\dock\scpdock.py", line 2503, in saveROItoShapefile
cfg.utls.calculateSignature(cfg.shpLay, cfg.bandSetsList[cfg.bndSetNumber][8], [self.ROILastID], cfg.ROIMacroID, cfg.ROIMacroClassInfo, cfg.ROIID, cfg.ROIInfo, 50, 40, "No", "No", UID)
File "C:/Users/ASUS/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin\core\utils.py", line 1739, in calculateSignature
ROIsize = cfg.utls.getROISize(bX, 1, rStat[0], rStat[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hY9k2.png))
File "C:/Users/ASUS/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin\core\utils.py", line 5672, in getROISize
s = ( (a >= min) & (a **FloatingPointError: invalid value encountered in greater_equal**

The error appears when saving ROI as training cells.[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Thanks for the question. Can you put a bit more info about your problem besides a dump of the error message. Like what you are trying to do, and what you have tried.